# UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE condition not working in wixui_install.wxs in library

Tags: wix

UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE condition not working in  wixui_install.wxs in library

I want to change the value of next button to respective dlg if first time install and for major upgrade.

This is not working in wix library.

Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="PortNoDlg" >LicenseAccepted = "1" AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE

Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg" >LicenseAccepted = "1" AND UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE

Answer (score 3):

[`UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372380.aspx) is set only for the hidden uninstallation of a package found via the [Upgrade table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372379.aspx) and [FindRelatedProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368600.aspx)/[RemoveExistingProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371197.aspx). This does not show any UI, so conditioning control events off of this property will not be helpful.

By contrast `UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` is not set for the newer installation. If you want to condition  your control events on whether a previous version will be uninstalled, you must reference the properties specified in the `ActionProperty` of each record in the Upgrade table.

Comment: I have done that in my project. so is there any other way which will distinguish which action to perform while first installation and which will be while major upgrade. I have tried with

Comment: "NEWER_VERSION_FOUND" AND "OLD_VERSION_FOUND"


<Upgrade Id="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)">  <UpgradeVersion 
Property="NEWER_VERSION_FOUND"                  OnlyDetect="yes" 
           Language="1033" 
Minimum="$(var.ProductFullVersion)" 
IncludeMinimum="no"/>  <UpgradeVersion Property="OLD_VERSION_FOUND" 
              OnlyDetect="no"                  Language="1033" 
         Minimum="$(var.ProductMinimumVersion)" 
Maximum="$(var.ProductFullVersion)" 
IncludeMinimum="yes"                  IncludeMaximum="no" 
    IgnoreRemoveFailure="yes" 
MigrateFeatures="yes"/></Upgrade>